# Sequelize hook depending on transaction

Tags: node.js, transactions, hook, sequelize.js

I want to create a sequelize hook on **afterCreate** on my user model. it work great when i just create a user without a transaction. but if i run my create statement in a transaction the hook is run before the commit.

user Model hooks

```
hooks: {
    afterCreate: userModule.NewUserHook,
    afterBulkCreate: userModule.NewUserHook
}
```

Hook function

```
NewUserHook: function NewUserHook(user, options){
    console.log('Inside hook');
}
```

The transaction is accesssible in options.transaction.

Is there anyway to run the hook after the transaction is commited?

Answer (score 12):

A bit late to the game but since I came across this question while searching for answers, this one may be useful for others.

If you create the user inside a transaction then the transaction object will be passed in one of the arguments of the hook callback (depending on version). [Link to docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/hooks.html#a-note-about-transactions). 
The following is copied directly from the source link:

```
// Here we use the promise-style of async hooks rather than
// the callback.
User.hook('afterCreate', (user, options) => {
  // 'transaction' will be available in options.transaction

  // This operation will be part of the same transaction as the
  // original User.create call.
  return User.update({
    mood: 'sad'
  }, {
    where: {
      id: user.id
    },
    transaction: options.transaction
  });
});


sequelize.transaction(transaction => {
  User.create({
    username: 'someguy',
    mood: 'happy',
    transaction
  });
```

> If we had not included the transaction option in our call to `User.update` in the preceding code, no change would have occurred, since our newly created user does not exist in the database until the pending transaction has been committed.

Comment: you can use `afterCommit` hook for transactions.
updated link on sequelize site : https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/transactions/

Answer (score 0):

**`transaction` has to be present in the second argument of `create`, not the first as of 6.5.1**

I think this has changed a bit since [AlexandreF's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45928541/895245), now the transaction has to be given in the second argument of `create`. This makes sense, as otherwise it would potentially conflict with a field named `transaction`.

The current documentation section https://sequelize.org/master/manual/hooks.html#hooks-and-transactions ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506220730/https://sequelize.org/master/manual/hooks.html#hooks-and-transactions)) gives an example:

```
User.addHook('afterCreate', async (user, options) => {
  // We can use `options.transaction` to perform some other call
  // using the same transaction of the call that triggered this hook
  await User.update({ mood: 'sad' }, {
    where: {
      id: user.id
    },
    transaction: options.transaction
  });
});

await sequelize.transaction(async t => {
  await User.create({
    username: 'someguy',
    mood: 'happy'
  }, {
    transaction: t
  });
});
```

rather than putting `transaction` together with `username` and `mood`.